# Bash script callstack when you only have read/exec priviledge

Tags: bash, callstack

I have a bunch scripts which are calling each other. I want to find out the stack trace of these scripts. But I only have exec and read priviledge on them. If anyone can suggest me a solution i would be grateful.

Br,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may get your desired information using the [xtrace](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html) feature of bash. You can apply it to a non-changeable script by

```
set -x
export SHELLOPTS
./your_start_script.sh
```

You can then see a lot of output on stderr, which you can analyse.